# Branded version of windows application

Tags: .net

What is the best method to create branded verion for .net windows application.

Comment: A little more words would help!

Answer (score 2):

Use a build tool such as nant or msbuild that with provided parameters, will take specific resources files instead of the originals. It works great and that can be fully automated without having to change your app. All you have to do is to put brandables items such as logos and texts in external resources.

Answer (score 1):

Write the Company name and Copyright message in [assembly information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h52t681(VS.80).aspx) of your application. That should brand the application for you.